# pass class name as argument to function

Tags: c#

Is it possible to pass ClassA as argument without using typeof or initializing it?

```
class ClassA {
}

class ClassB {
     public void Function([something here] clazz) {
                  ......
     }
}

class ClassC {

     public void main() {
         ClassB asdf = new ClassB();
         asdf.Function(ClassA);   // pass like that, not typeof() or something else
     }
}
```

Comment: I suspect you might have an XY problem...

Comment: How is that function using ClassA?

Comment: If your requirement is to make exactly `asdf.Function(ClassA);` work and not "typeof() or something else" then it's impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can pass the type as a generic parameter.

```
class ClassA {
}

class ClassB {
    public void Function<T>() {
              ......
    }


class ClassC {
    public void main() {
        ClassB asdf = new ClassB();
        asdf.Function<ClassA>();   // magic
    }
}
```

This sort of thing is very common with IoC containers and autofactories:

```
var o = container.Resolve<SomeClassName>();
```